# Single make and parallel tests in Travis

Tags: c++, makefile, travis-ci

I need to run once:

```
autoreconf -i
mkdir build && cd build
../configure
make
```

and then run tests in different folders:

```
make check -C path1
make check -C path2
```

The tests can be parallelized with Matrix feature:

```
language:
    - cpp
compiler:
    - clang
env:
    - TEST_PATH=path1
    - TEST_PATH=path2
install:
    - autoreconf --install
    - mkdir build && cd build
    - ../configure
    - make
script:
    - make check -C $TEST_PATH
```

The problem is: the *install* step runs **twice**, e.g.:

- install + test path1
- install + test path2

Is there a way to achieve something like:

- install (runs once)
- run 2 jobs with tests (the *script* part of the Travis config):

  - test path1
  - test path2

Comment: Assuming you parallelize the test doesn't this mean they can run on different hosts? Assuming they run on different hosts doesn't that *require* the installation to be done on each one?

Comment: Sure thing, assuming they are run on different hosts. Travis documentation says that jobs running for more than 50 mins will be killed. The status page shows total amount of time spent, e.g.: dT_test1 + dT_test2. Does Travis timeout jobs based on total time or individual test dT_i?

Comment: Are you indicating that even for the same host the install runs twice? I'm assuming each job runs in its own environment of some sort so they might very well be different hosts as far as the test jobs are concerned. (I'll point out I know nothing about how travis actually works I'm just going on general principals here.) Where does timing jobs out come into play here at all?

Comment: That's the primary question: if test are run independently on the same host (parallel processes) then I do not see a reason to run the install step twice. However, if (as you said) they run on different hosts or different virtual machines, etc. then obviously the install step needs to be run twice. The timing is important to speed up testing. For example, given a node with N cores I can run `make -j N -C path1` which dramatically speeds up test builds. Moreover I can test path1 and path2 in parallel but it needs to be done with two separate processes instead of environments.

Comment: Ok, so the timing thing is a different question entirely then. And no, your assumption is faulty. Teaching the CI system that two jobs running (in parallel) on the same host can share the same install requires more work than simply treating two parallel jobs on the same host *exactly* the same as you treat two jobs running in parallel on different hosts. Each job needs to run *as if* it is running on its own to function. Building support for short-circuiting is extra (potentially fragile) work that otherwise isn't necessary. But since I'm just speculating I'll shut up now.

Comment: Thanks for sharing thoughts. Most likely it is implemented exactly the way you describe. Otherwise the system would not run the install twice. I see no other logical explanation to this.